# Read registry key values

Tags: c++

I created the following location in the registry, "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\PAQ".

I have the following registry keys (names) within this location; ak,hk,hv,jk,lk,mk,mv,ra,&ru.

How can I create a c++ function to read the Data as a string from the each aforementioned registry key and put each data in its respective string name?

My c++ project character set is a 'Multi-Byte Character Set' with no whole program optimization.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724871(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ooga, clearly the user does not know how to do this and also that link does not specify on how to read values...therefore, your link is useless.

Comment: First switch to unicode

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf, I stated that I am using multi-byte character set. I have no intentions to switch to unicode.

Comment: things get a lot simpler when you match the native encoding of windows. otherwise you have silly lossy conversions everywhere. using MBCS for a new native windows app today, is exceedingly counter-productive. but you can of course ignore all advice you get here. and maybe you're maintaining a 200 KLOC legacy code thingy.

Comment: some of my code relies on multi byte character set...

Answer (score 0):

To access data from the Windows Registry you need to use the Windows SDK [Registry Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724875%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**Edit:** To convert between the different string formats just use the SDK [string functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06b9yaeb.aspx).

Comment: Is it possible to use this with a Multi-Byte character set?

Comment: The Windows SDK has function to convert between the different characters sets.